# Org Migration - Behaviour of batch jobs during downtime

Tags: apex, batch, administration, schedulebatch, org

Our org is slated to move from AP13 to AUS64 next week.

The expected downtime is from 2 AM - 6 AM AEST (Sydney).

Fortunately we do not have much user activity during this window but we have batch jobs that run during this time.

Any idea as to what happens to those batch jobs slated to run during this time ?

Say these are the 4 batch jobs that runs during this window

- B1 runs at 1:30 AM - 2:30 AM
- B2 runs at 3:00 AM - 5:00 AM
- B3 runs at 6:00 AM - 7:00 AM
- B4 runs at 7:00 AM (this expects B1 and B2 have completed their execution)

Can someone let us know what will happen if no action is done from us ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ongoing activities will be paused prior to the instance refresh and resumed following the instance refresh. Activities scheduled during the instance refresh will start following the completion of the maintenance.

A small subset of Apex, Batch Apex, REST API, SOAP API, and Bulk API jobs started prior to the instance refresh may return an error following the maintenance window. If you receive an error resulting from a previously scheduled job following the maintenance window, restarting the job will return the expected results. It is recommended to rescheduling large or long-running jobs after the instance refresh completes for the most seamless experience.

Best practice would be to unschedule the batch jobs before migration and re-schedule them again if it is feasible for you.

Check more details on [Instance Refresh Maintenance](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387056&type=1).